# Sort a List of Image Names in Groovy

Tags: list, sorting, collections, groovy, comparator

I'm trying to sort a list of images names. For simplicity I have placed this in an example Groovy list of the form:

```
imageNames=[
'20131018PKH26DRAQ5HOECHST1_A01_T0001F001L01A01Z01C01.tif',
'20131018PKH26DRAQ5HOECHST1_A01_T0001F001L01A01Z01C03.tif',
'20131018PKH26DRAQ5HOECHST1_A01_T0001F001L01A02Z01C04.tif',
'20131018PKH26DRAQ5HOECHST1_A01_T0001F001L01A03Z01C02.tif'
]
```

I would like to be able to sort this list in the numerical order of any of the T,F,L,A,Z or C codes that are present in the suffix of the image names.

So for example, if the list was to be sorted in terms of the C code it should appear in the following order:

1. '20131018PKH26DRAQ5HOECHST1_A01_T0001F001L01A01Z01C01.tif',
2. '20131018PKH26DRAQ5HOECHST1_A01_T0001F001L01A03Z01C02.tif',
3. '20131018PKH26DRAQ5HOECHST1_A01_T0001F001L01A01Z01C03.tif',
4. '20131018PKH26DRAQ5HOECHST1_A01_T0001F001L01A02Z01C04.tif'

I have thought of using the default Groovy collection sort method using a comparator. However, I'm not sure how to write a comparator directly into a closure.
I would like something like

> imageNames.sort{comparator_for_C}

where I can write specific comparators for each of the T,F,L,A,Z and C codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the name of the image files remains the same till the 2nd `_`, you can skip the splitting in the logic below. I wanted to be on the safe side.

```
def imageNames=[
'20131018PKH26DRAQ5HOECHST1_A01_T0001F001L01A01Z01C01.tif',
'20131018PKH26DRAQ5HOECHST1_A01_T0001F001L01A01Z01C03.tif',
'20131018PKH26DRAQ5HOECHST1_A01_T0001F001L01A02Z01C04.tif',
'20131018PKH26DRAQ5HOECHST1_A01_T0001F001L01A03Z01C02.tif'
]

def comparator = {str->
    [
      compare: {a,b->
          a.split(/_/)[2].dropWhile{it != str} <=> 
          b.split(/_/)[2].dropWhile{it != str}
      }
    ] as Comparator
}

def comp = ['T', 'F', 'A', 'Z', 'C'].collectEntries{[it, comparator(it)]}

assert imageNames.sort(comp.'C') == [
'20131018PKH26DRAQ5HOECHST1_A01_T0001F001L01A01Z01C01.tif',
'20131018PKH26DRAQ5HOECHST1_A01_T0001F001L01A03Z01C02.tif',
'20131018PKH26DRAQ5HOECHST1_A01_T0001F001L01A01Z01C03.tif',
'20131018PKH26DRAQ5HOECHST1_A01_T0001F001L01A02Z01C04.tif'
]
```

Same would be applicable for other characters as:

```
imageNames.sort(comp.'A')
imageNames.sort(comp.'T') ....
```

Comment: Nice! If the comparator works like he prefers this is a nice solution.

Comment: In addition to providing a usable and elegant solution this answer introduced me to the dropWhile method that I was not aware off. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just make the comparators separately something like this should work-

```
   def comparator_for_c = { }
   def sortedList = imageNames.sort(comparator_for_c)
```

Or Alternately something like this:

```
def comparators = [c:{}, t:{}, ...]
def sortedListForC = imageNames.sort(comparators.c)
```

AS sample code:

```
def imageNames = ['20131018PKH26DRAQ5HOECHST1_A01_T0001F001L01A01Z01C01.tif',
'20131018PKH26DRAQ5HOECHST1_A01_T0001F001L01A01Z01C03.tif',
'20131018PKH26DRAQ5HOECHST1_A01_T0001F001L01A02Z01C04.tif',
'20131018PKH26DRAQ5HOECHST1_A01_T0001F001L01A03Z01C02.tif']

def sorters = [sort_c:{a, b -> b <=> a }, sort_t:{}]

println "DefaultSort ${imageNames.sort()}"

println "c sort: ${imageNames.sort(sorters.sort_c)}"
```

Just put your custom comparators in the sorters map and call which one you want.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
imageNames.sort { def a, def b ->
    def rank = 0

    def matcherA = (a =~ /.*(...)\.tif/)
    def codeA = matcherA[0][1]
    def matcherB = (b =~ /.*(...)\.tif/)
    def codeB = matcherB[0][1]

    // add your own comparison logic here as desired:        
    rank = codeA.compareTo(codeB)

    rank
}
```